# Difficulty in handling the ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, httpresponse

I have a problem in which I am calling a url through ajax, but I am having some problem in handling the response.

The [url](http://www.amazon.com/gp/aag/ajax/paginatedFeedback.html?seller=A3QGTRL0G4B98R&isAmazonFulfilled=&isCBA=&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER&asin=&ref_=aag_m_fb&&currentPage=1) is returning the response, when I directly call it from the browser, but when I am using it in my ajax call I am having some problem in handling it.
I have used both the property(responseText and responseXML) of the XMLHTTPREQUEST object.

my code is::

```
function postRequest(strURL) 
    {
        var xmlHttp;
          if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // Mozilla, Safari, ... 
          { 
            
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
           }

          else if (window.ActiveXObject)  // IE
          {
                var xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
    
          xmlHttp.open('GET', strURL, true);
          xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
            
          xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
          {
              if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
                {
                   alert("Status =4");
                   alert(xmlHttp.responseXML);
                   alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
             }
                 
          }
      
          xmlHttp.send(strURL);
      }
```

The url is:: `http://www.amazon.com/gp/aag/ajax/paginatedFeedback.html?seller=A3QGTRL0G4B98R&isAmazonFulfilled=&isCBA=&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER&asin=&ref_=aag_m_fb&&currentPage=1`

Please suggest anything.

Comment: If you are doing an AJAX call to amazon.com you are probably going to have problems with cross domain origin policy.

Comment: Unless you have a good reason not to I would recommend using JQuery's AJAX functionality, it takes a LOT of the hassle out of doing AJAX calls.

Comment: @vcsjones: what is that and how to overcome?

Comment: @SashiKant cross domain origin policy means browsers won't make AJAX requests to a domain other than the domain of the current page. You cannot overcome this (unless you work for Amazon). It is a security measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can't make calls to another domain. You can read more about AJAX Cross-Domain in G